# Attempt to invoke interface method '...' on a null object reference

Tags: android, callback

I'm working on an App with Bluetooth functionalities. I use a fragment to scan for and list bluetooth device. On click there is a callback to the main activity providing the selected bluetooth device. 
I started with a Smartphone with Android 6 (API 23) and then had to adapt the code for the use with Android 5.0 (API 21). 
I just changed the minSDK to API21 and rebuilt the project without any problems. 
 
The App works without any problems on the smartphone. The Tablet with Android 5 runs the app but crashes with a null pointer exception when I select a bluetooth device.

I have not found any solution to this problem and dont know how to proceed. Maybe someone can help? :-)

The Log is:

```
me: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.tuhh.et5.tills.biocontrol, PID: 26512
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void de.tuhh.et5.tills.biocontrol.activity.BLEListFragment$OnBLEDeviceSelectedListener.OnBLEDeviceSelected(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice)' on a null object reference                                                                                    at de.tuhh.et5.tills.biocontrol.activity.BLEListFragment.onListItemClick(BLEListFragment.java:92)
at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1185)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3222)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4138)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5568)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

Since it is a lot of code I'll try to summarize the important pieces of code:

The error refers to this method

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView mBluetoothLeDeviceList, View v, int position, long id) {
    if(DEBUG)d("onListItemClick()");
    mBluetoothLeDeviceList.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); // set background
    mBluetoothLeDeviceList.getChildAt(position).setFocusable(false); // not clickable again
    mCallback.OnBLEDeviceSelected(mListAdapter.getDevice(position));
}
```

The last line with the mCallback... generates the Null Pointer Exception. The Bluetooth device is definetly not null, so there must be a problem with the callback that just appears under android 5.0 (doesnt sound right to me :-)  )

The callback is created:

```
OnBLEDeviceSelectedListener mCallback;
```

and the interface

```
public interface OnBLEDeviceSelectedListener {
    void OnBLEDeviceSelected(BluetoothDevice device);
}
```

and this makes sure the listener is implemented in the main activity:

```
try {
        mCallback = (OnBLEDeviceSelectedListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnBLEDeviceeSelectedListener");
    }
```

The main activity implements BLEListFragment.OnBLEDeviceSelectedListener and contains

```
@Override
public void OnBLEDeviceSelected(BluetoothDevice device) {
.
.
.}
```

Thats about it. I find it very weird, that it works on one device and just crashes on the other one without any compiling errors.

I appreciate any idea or hints.

Thanks & Greetings

Comment: Debug and find out which value is being null

Comment: I checked if  mListAdapter or mListAdapter.getDevice(position) is null which wasn't the case. I guess its something with the callback. Weird thing is, that the same code works with API23 but not with API21. There are no compiling errors, just this runtime crash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Make sure you implement both methods in fragment like this.

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    //Your callback initialization here
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    //Your callback initialization here
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I was aware of the activity/context differences but did not know that overloading is possible. Thanks, great answer :-)

Comment: This is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

Implement these methods in the fragment its very important.

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
   
    if (context instanceof mCallback) {
        mCallback = (OnBLEDeviceSelectedListener) context;
    }else{
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
            + " must implement OnBLEDeviceeSelectedListener");

    // or you can throw runtime exception like this
    //  throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must 
   //implement OnBLEDeviceeSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallback =null;
}
```