# My app closes right when I launch and I do not know why

Tags: crash, logcat

I created an app with buildozer android, and it built successfully but when I try to run it on my phone, it crashes. I tried doing a logcat, but I have no idea when to stop it or how to know what is going on. Please read through the logcat or ask any questions that may help you figure out what the error is. The package name is gh41app1, and the name is GH41Beta. Thank you in advance.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rao5yRGi1o7ne6k_9e5UWfrjsFm0rGx0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Probably this is a error, but it crashes the app. You just have to find it.

Comment: I know it is a error, but i don't know what it is or how to go through the logcat to find it, Which is why i am asking for help.

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371926/attempt-to-invoke-interface-method-on-a-null-object-reference) might help.
This is the problem: `Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.samsung.android.pass.IPassService.getPassVersion()' on a null object reference`